# NodeJS: node-opencv install warnings, node app crash

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv

I've seen issues reported on Github and Stack similar to mine, but I can't resolve.

I have a node.js app that crashes on the im.save('test.jpg'); line. If I comment that line out, it appears to run fine. Relevant code:

```
var cv = require('opencv');
var camera = new cv.VideoCapture(0);
camera.read(function(err, im) {
    im.save('test.jpg');
});
```

The crash reports this:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2cv7imwriteERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS0_6vectorIiNS4_IiEEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/wys3/node_modules/opencv/build/Release/opencv.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2cv7imwriteERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS0_6vectorIiNS4_IiEEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/wys3/node_modules/opencv/build/Release/opencv.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

OpenCV 2.4.8.2 appears to install on my Mac with OS X 10.8.5 through Homebrew just fine.

I install node-opencv with npm and I get this output with warnings:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv

> opencv@0.5.0 preinstall /usr/local/node_modules/opencv
> node-gyp clean rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/Matrix.o
../src/Matrix.cc:119:13: warning: variable 'mat' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false
      [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
        } else if (args.Length() == 5) {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/Matrix.cc:128:2: note: uninitialized use occurs here
        mat->Wrap(args.Holder());
        ^~~
../src/Matrix.cc:119:9: note: remove the 'if' if its condition is always true
        } else if (args.Length() == 5) {
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/Matrix.cc:113:13: note: initialize the variable 'mat' to silence this warning
        Matrix *mat;
                   ^
                    = nullptr
../src/Matrix.cc:1147:22: warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'ret' returned
      [-Wreturn-stack-address]
        return (cv::Rect*) &ret;
                            ^~~
2 warnings generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/OpenCV.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/CascadeClassifierWrap.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/Contours.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/Point.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/VideoCaptureWrap.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/CamShift.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/HighGUI.o
../src/HighGUI.cc:38:13: warning: variable 'win' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false
      [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
        } else if (args.Length() == 2){
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/HighGUI.cc:42:2: note: uninitialized use occurs here
        win->Wrap(args.Holder());
        ^~~
../src/HighGUI.cc:38:9: note: remove the 'if' if its condition is always true
        } else if (args.Length() == 2){
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/HighGUI.cc:35:19: note: initialize the variable 'win' to silence this warning
  NamedWindow* win;
                  ^
                   = nullptr
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/FaceRecognizer.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/opencv.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/opencv.node: Finished
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers/0.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers/0.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers/0.1.1
opencv@0.5.0 node_modules/opencv
└── buffers@0.1.1
```

Comment: The Readme states that you need to have OpenCV 2.3.1 installed. Do you experience your problems with this version?

Comment: I tried downgrading OpenCV to several versions, including 2.3.1, and they won't compile correctly. Got different warnings/errors in each case.

Comment: I tried again and got the following OpenCV 2.3.1 installed, but with a ton of warnings, and node app throws the same errors.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/cdaf83d119cda000174b75f75fdab18fc64ec1cc/opencv.rb

Comment: Sorry, make that: the reinstall of node-opencv is with a ton of warnings post-install of OpenCV 2.3.1.

Comment: Kept rolling node-opencv back and 0.3.0 works (albeit with lots of install warnings) alongside OpenCV 2.3.1.